# SQL "chained" queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have two tables.

I am a total newbie to SQL. Using mysql at the moment.
I have the following setup for a school-related db:

**Table A** contains students records.
Student's id, password,name, lastname and so on.

**Table B** contains class attendancy records. 
Each record goes like this:  date, student id, grade

I need to gather all the student info of students that attended classes in a certain date range.

Now, the stupid way would be

1. first I `SELECT all classes from Table B with DATE IN BETWEEN the range`
2. then for each class, I get the student id and `SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = student id`

What I can't wrap my mind around is the smart way.
How to do this in one query only.
I am failing at understanding the concepts of JOIN, UNION and so on...

my best guess so far is

```
SELECT students.id, students.name, students.lastname 
FROM students, classes
WHERE classes.date BETWEEN 20140101 AND 20150101 
AND 
classes.studentid = students.id
```

but is this the appropriate way for this case?

Comment: Have you got the solution? adam_b

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins/38578#38578). Also, `WHERE classes.date BETWEEN <date 1> AND <date 2>`  (no `IN`)

Comment: Other than the syntax error mentioned above. What is the issue with the query? by joining the 2 tables you are just querying once.

Comment: TheProvost, the query works, I just thought there was a better way involving join or union.. which I currently don't understand yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont add the join statement in the where clause. Do it like this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.lastname,c.date,c.grade 
FROM classes c
inner join students s
on c.studentid=s.id
WHERE c.date BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '01/01/2015'
```

Comment: thanks, I think this is what I was looking for, as it improves on my query while implicitly explaning how JOIN works

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an assignment so I will attempt to describe the problem and give a hint to the solution.

## An example of a union would be;

```
SELECT students.name, students.lastname
FROM students
WHERE students.lastname IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT students.name, 'N/A'
FROM students
WHERE students.lastname IS NULL;

+--------------+--------------+
| name         | lastname     |
+--------------+--------------+
| John         | Doe          |   <- First two rows came from first query
| Jill         | Smith        |
| Bill         | N/A          |   <- This came from the second query
+--------------+--------------+
```

The usual use case for a union is to display the same columns, but munge the data in a different way - otherwise you can usually achieve similar results through a `WHERE` clause.

## An example of a join would be;

```
SELECT authors.id, authors.name, books.title
FROM authors LEFT JOIN books ON authors.id = books.authors_id

+--------------+--------------+------------------+
| id           | name         | title            |
+--------------+--------------+------------------+   
| 1            | Mark Twain   | Huckleberry Fin. |
| 2            | Terry Prat.. | Good Omens       |
+--------------+--------------+------------------+   
    ^ First two columns from     ^ Third column appended
      from authors table           from books table linked
                                   by "author id"
```

Think of a join as appending columns to your results, a union is appending rows with the same columns.

In your situation we can rule out a union as you don't want to append more student rows, you want class and student information side by side.

Comment: Join, not left join :)

Comment: I wish it was an assignment. I am 73 years old :)  Thanks for the hint

Comment: @adam_b; OK :) I think TheProvost has given the final answer, hope my explanation helped.